# MongoDB - How to query in a large database

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have an Order collection in MongoDB like this:

```
{"user_id": 1, "order_id": 1, "order_value": 1000, "createdAt": "2018-09-22T10:32:43.566Z"}
{"user_id": 1, "order_id": 2, "order_value": 2000, "createdAt": "2018-09-23T10:32:43.566Z"}
{"user_id": 2, "order_id": 3, "order_value": 500, "createdAt": "2018-09-24T10:32:43.566Z"}
{"user_id": 2, "order_id": 4, "order_value": 1500, "createdAt": "2018-09-24T10:32:43.566Z"}
```

The problem is pretty simple too, just to calculate total order's value group by "user_id" for every month:

```
{"user_id": 1, "total_order_value": 3000, "year": "2018", "month": "09"}
{"user_id": 2, "total_order_value": 2000, "year": "2018", "month": "09"}
```

The solution I know and already used is by using Aggregation in MongoDB. But when the number of users and orders increase, by hundred thousand or even million documents, the query will soon be slow down (the query will be excuted by a Nodejs server). Pagination is an option too, but I need to extract all the order's value for all users into sheet.

So, I want to ask for some suggestion and advance for my problem and also the database design. Many thanks later!

Comment: What is the query’s size when tested locally ?

Comment: can you post your current used aggregation query? Do you have indexes on your collection

Comment: Yes, I have indexed "user_id" in Order schema

Answer (score 1):

pagination might be what you are looking for, and because you combine it with synchronous node.js you can run multiple paginating queries limiting the time easily. it will be a bit heavier with the performance but you can handle that easily, i think.

here is more information on it:
https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate

Comment: Yes, sorry for mistaking in the question description. This function is for excute entire data of all user to a file (ex: excel sheet), so i need to query all the users

Comment: have you ever tought about replacing your dataschemes to a different model?
i see you have different objects for all user_id's why not combine all of them by using an array inside your database. it would save you alot of time retrieving those records.

Comment: `{"user_id":1, "order":[{"order_id": 1, "order_value": 1000, "createdAt": "2018-09-22T10:32:43.566Z"},{"order_id": 2, "order_value": 2000, "createdAt": "2018-09-23T10:32:43.566Z"}]}`

Comment: then all you have do is get one record with the user_id 1 instead of a 1000+

Comment: Thanks @Lars Hendriks. Due to the use of the Order schema, for some reason such as get list of orders of an user and paginate, sort by time,... them, I can not store them like array  in a schema.